# data from file into multidimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays, file, multidimensional-array, console-application

I need to loop through a .txt document called archive.txt until all data is in the document is exhausted.

I'm trying to return the data in a multidimensional array that creates a new row for every eighth data point.

So far, I have managed to loop through the data but can not seem to organise it.

Below is the function that can only spit out the data line per line.

```
private void findContract() {

 Scanner input = null; // this is to keep the compiler happy
 // as the object initialisation is in a separate block                                            
 try {

  input = new Scanner(new File("archive.txt"));

 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
  System.exit(1);
 }

 while (input.hasNext()) {
  String dDate = input.next();
  System.out.println(dDate);
 }

 input.close();
}
```

Example of first 8 data points from text file (archive.txt)

```
15-Sep-2015 2   1   12  N   MT230N  617 CMcgee
```

The outcome of all of this is I need to be able to select a data point by row & column.

If anyone could show me the correct way it would be hugely appreciated. I have tried several methods & the above function is the last instance where it displays the data from the file.

Comment: Read the whole line and use `String#split`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that or how I could get it to repeat every eighth data point. 

Is there any way you could show me an example of what I need to put in the while loop? :)

Comment: [java string split](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=java%20string%20split)

Comment: It already splits. It displays each of the example data points on a separate line. I'm trying to turn that in to a multidimensional array which creates a new row every eighth data point. (imaging the row of data you see in my question but repeated vertically 100 times)

Comment: So each entry is on it's own line?  It's very unclear from your question what the original structure of the file is

Comment: The file data is a large collection of 8 points of data that is repeated without any breaks. I have managed to (by the code above) display each data point from the file on a line of its own. Now my problem is organising the list that I am now producing into a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

With java 8 you can use this for any delimiter you may be using.

```
  public static String[][] fileToMatriz(String file, String delimiter) throws IOException {  
      try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))) {
          return stream.map(s -> s.split(delimiter))
                       .toArray(String[][]::new);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this in between the above while & am getting this error '  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression
 at contractmanager.Menu.findContract(Menu.java:106)
 at contractmanager.Menu.performAction(Menu.java:69)
 at contractmanager.Menu.runMenu(Menu.java:26)
 at contractmanager.Menu.main(Menu.java:19)
Java Result: 1 '